# Individually Animate Each Character on a Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently I have a mostly working script I've hobbled together. I'm doing this in multiple phases to make it as modular as possible.

```
//This grabs every element on page.
$('body').find('*').each(function(){
//This filters for text nodes only
$(this).contents().filter(function() { return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;       }).each(function(){
    //Wraps each text node in a span.
    $(this).wrap("<span class='text'></span>")
});
})
//
$('.text').each(function(){
    //Splits each text node into a character array and wraps each char in a span.
    var test = $(this).text().split('');
        var curStr = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
           if(test[i] !=  " " || test[i] != ''){
            curStr = curStr + "<span class='char'>" +test[i] + "</span>";
           } else {
            curStr = curStr + test[i];
           }
        }
        $(this).html(curStr);
})
```

My issue come from trying to style the elements at random. I'm using the following code to do so:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $($('.char')[Math.floor((Math.random()*$('.char').length)+1)]).each(function(){
        $(this).css('color', 'green');
        $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        $(this).animate({
        top: $(window).height + 'px'
    }, 1000, 'swing', function(){$(this).remove()});
    })  
    }, 100)
```

The issue with this is, it manages to apply the color styling, but my position and animate don't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) method requires parentheses:

Change this:

```js
top: $(window).height + 'px'
```

To this:

```
top: $(window).height() + 'px'
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vEbQL/1/)

Comment: I was so hyper focused on getting the initial stuff, I failed at paying attention to the issue being inside the animate.

Also, while looking this over I ran the fixed script on the page and then got busy with a meeting, came back and though you had edited your comment to just be garbled, then remembered the script was running: http://i.imgur.com/5j4Cqkl.png

Comment: Used with a few tweaks to setting page color and I've now got a somewhat workable "Matrix" effect that might be going on my office's directory as an "easter egg"